# Feature APK's and Android Instant Apps

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

According to this doc : https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/overview.html#features
In case I want to make a modular app with installable feature, can I use instant app to imitate the behavior of a module ? I want a base app with very basic features and installable modules to fit perfectly the needs of users. It could be a plus if modules can be found on the play store too.

Thanks if you have more info about it or if Google have another way to archieve this :)

Comment: Why?  Its easier to put everything in one apk, and turn on/off features than to download new features later on.

Comment: Hello Gabe and thanks for your answer. Of course I considered it but I have several app on the play store, and I want to modularize them. Each app could install modules but different app can install the same modules. With this appoach, each app is personalized.

Comment: I recommend watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oispNrpGnIY), to get a first hand knowledge of Android Instant Apps first.

Comment: As per my understanding, Instant Apps is basically the main installable-app broken down to lite-modularized apps that are accessed via URLs and loaded automatically without the need to go to the Play Store to install the entire app. For more understanding please also have a look at https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/overview.html

Comment: Yes you're right, not the tool I need ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, Instant Apps is basically the main installable-app broken down to lite-modularized apps that are accessed via URLs and loaded automatically without the need to go to the Play Store to install the entire app. For more understanding please also have a look at
[Overview of Android Instant Apps](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/overview.html) and  [Introduction to Android Instant Apps (Google I/O '17)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oispNrpGnIY)